# gcloud erase deprecated/obsolete/deleted custom VM images

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

As far as I understood from the [gcloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/deprecate), there is no way to automatically delete custom VM images, even after marking it with `--delete-in | --delete-on` marks.

Okay, I'd gather all deprecated all obsolete images in the list and use each entry for
`gcloud compute images delete` command. Good plan, AFAICS :)

I'm trying to gather deprecated images with filtering, but it looks like every time I'm getting the combined result (not only deprecated images are shown).
[image]
I assume the filter is broken, or it might be I missing something..

So the question is how to erase deprecated/obsolete/deleted custom images with gcloud cli?

thank you,
P.

Comment: Are you trying to delete a custom image?

Comment: Yep, that's true

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to delete an image even if it is deprecated/obsolete/deleted you can as long that it is a custom image.

```
gcloud compute images delete my-image1 my-image2
```

However if you're trying to delete a pre-existing image (deprecated/obsolete/deleted) you cannot delete that because it is a google cloud features.